Optimal strategy in a selection game
Nate is given a chance to play a game - there are $n \geq 2$ turns. On each turn, he is given a number, uniformly drawn from $[0, 1]$ independent of other draws. On that turn, he may choose to either keep the number or discard the number.
At the end of the game, he is given a payoff equal to the average of all kept numbers. The payoff defaults to $0$ if no numbers are chosen.
Question: What is the optimal strategy to maximise the expected value of the game? And what is the expected payoff? That is, how much should Nate be willing to pay to play this game, assuming linear utility?

Once you have chosen a number, then the strategy is obvious, right? So really the question is when do you first choose a number?

@user479223 I think a case could be made that if it doesn’t increase the average by enough, it shouldn’t be worth choosing. Because having more numbers already chosen dampens the possible swings when you do draw large ones.

That’s right. I don’t know how you are able to make problems with so many wrong obvious answers…

If I didn't mess up my computations, the expected value (under optimal play) for $n = 2$ is $\frac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{6} \approx 0.638$, with the optimal strategy being to choose the first number iff it's at least $\sqrt{2}-1 \approx 0.414$, and to choose the second number iff it's at least the first number.

For n=3, I get: On the first round, accept if and only if the offer exceeds about .5506. On the second round, if you've accepted A on the first round, accept if and only if the offer exceeds $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{3+2a+a^2} -4 -a$
. On the second round, if you have not accepted on the first round, you are in @mathworker21 's world.

The answer if you can just choose $1$ number is $1-\frac{2}{n}$ up to lower order terms (proof: use the recursion $f(n) = \underset{0 \le t \le 1}{\max} \bigl[ t f(n-1) + (1-t)\frac{1+t}{2} \bigr] = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(f(n-1)^2+1\bigr)$), so that's a lower bound for our problem. And the expected maximum of $n$ uniform numbers from $[0,1]$ is $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$, which is obviously then an upper bound for our problem. So the "large $n$" question comes down to the constant, which I think could be interesting!

FYI:  It occurred to me that if instead of simple averages, you took weighted averages with some well-chosen weights, the problem might get a lot less messy.  It provably doesn't work, in the sense that you're always going to be taking square roots of polynomials that are not squares.

If you greedily keep a number if it's larger than your current average, you get $1-O(1/n^{1/3})$ in expectation (you can see this by setting up a recursive formula for the sum and total number of numbers kept)
